# Need explanation of basic JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I am completely new to JavaScript and I try to understand some basic code.

I need explanation of what's going on in this code:

```
circles = d3.range(numDisks).map(function(i) {
      return {
        index: i,
        x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - radius * 2) + radius),
        y: Math.round(Math.random() * (height - radius * 2) + radius)
      };
    });
```

I don't need explanation of math round/random etc.

I need to understand what data structure is built and how to delete elements from this data structure? Not null-them out but complete remove with a shift or whatever.

Thanks you

Comment: [`d3.range`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#range) returns an array, so the map method there is just the standard [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which also returns an array. In this case, since the map callback is returning an object, it will be an array of objects

Comment: btw, the above is not necessarily basic code.  It is code from a library (called d3.js) that is used for diagraming and data charts - In this case, it returns an array of objects. Each object has three attributes: id, x, y.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the data structure created is just an array of objects.  Starting with the d3.range function which returns an array of objects which you then map into a new array of objects with the array map operator

you can't remove items in an array map operator as map transforms all objects in the original array, you need to add a filter operator before or after the map with the removal logic.

```
circles = d3.range(numDisks).map(function(i) {
  return {
    index: i,
    x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - radius * 2) + radius),
    y: Math.round(Math.random() * (height - radius * 2) + radius)
  };
}).filter(i => i.x !== 0); // this filter removes items where their x value = 0
```